# How to import CSV into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin, csv-import

Respected,

I have problems with importing CSV into PostgreSQL via pgAdmin. No matter what I do, it shows the following error:

```
ERROR: extra data after last expected column.
```

Can anyone please help me and point me out a possible solution?

Thank you.
Milorad K.

Answer (score 0):

check that your data is formatted as postgresql expects it to be

That error could be caused by specifying the wrong quote character or the wrong field separator. or it could be that your input file is corrupt.

I've had corrupt CSV files from banks before, so don't trust anyone.

Comment: I have tried the simplest input possible: created new excel with 15x columns (from A1 till A15) and with 5x rows (from 1 till 5 in every column). Saved as CSV with UTF8 and delimiter ;. After on import in PostgreSQL via pgAdmin, I set all the details and shows again the same error as trying to import csv db with a lot of data and same structure as I created. Any hints to check?